# Is there an efficient algorithm for finding rows that have the same sum of column values up to a threshold value?

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

I have a table like this (more specifically a nested dictionary)

```
  img   a    b    c   d   e   
1 img   0    0    1   0   1   
2 img   3    1    0   0   2
3 img   4    0    0   0   1   
4 img   2    2    0   0   0   
5 img   0    0    0   0   2    
6 img   2    2    0   0   0
7 img   1    0    0   1   0
8 img   0    1    1   0   1
9 img   0    0    0   0   0
10img   0    1    0   0   0
```

I need to add all the column names upto a threshold value, I need those rows which would give me the same sum for all columns.

for example, If I keep 5 as a threshold then it should give rows which sums upto 5 (5 a-> 5, b->5, c->5, d->5, e->5, f->5) and as it iterates through each rows, column should not exceed the threshold.

One way I thought of this was to add iteratively until one class fills up and then stop counting for that class. I n my case

```
  a b c d e
1img 0 0 1 0 1
2img 3 1 1 0 3
*3img 7 0 0 0 1* (skips this as this exceeds the threshold)
4img 5 3 1 0 3 (a is full, ignores entire row for which has value for class a)
5img 0 3 1 0 5 (e is full, ignores entire row for which has value for class a and e)
*6img 2 2 0 0 0* (since now a will become 7, it skips this step and jumps to next row)
```

and it should go on like that and finally returns those img which will satisfy the conditions. Sometimes the constraint cannot fill upto 5, so maybe at the end I try with 1 or 2 value more than threshold.

I made function manually which implements this exact same approach in python

```
def filter_by_threshold(threshold_value, data):
 .........
    for ing_key, value in data.items():
        skip_row = False

        for class, count in value.items():
            if class in max_counts:
                max_counts[class] = max(max_counts[class], count)
            else:
                max_counts[class] = count

            if count > threshold_value:
                skip_row = True
                break

        if skip_row:
            continue
...........
```

Is there any algorithm which does this exact same thing in a more efficient way? I am doing this in python defining as a function Will it work if I consider the class name such a,b,c... as nodes and values as weight of nodes and consider any graphical approach? Also, I don't want to use pandas dataframe.